# How to simple assign vectors of different structs?

Tags: c++, vector, struct

So I have two different structs (a & b) with same variables and an overloaded = operator in struct b to convert a to b.

I want to be able to simple assign a vector of a to a vector b, but compiler gives me an error:

```
main.cpp|61|error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::vector<_Ty>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)|
```

I assumed that I already had the overloaded = operator and that it would simply iterate over vector a and use that = operator for each instance. How would I do this?

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct a
{
    int x, y;
    a() {}
    a(int _x, int _y)
    {
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
    }
};

struct b
{
    int x, y;
    b(){}
    b(int _x, int _y)
    {
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
    }

    b& operator=(const a& _a)
    {
        x = _a.x;
        y = _a.y;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    a a_test(1,2);

    std::vector<a> a_vec;
    std::vector<b> b_vec;

    for(int i = 0; i <10; i++)
    {
        a_vec.push_back(a_test);
    }

    /*
    for(int i = 0; i<a_vec.size(); i++)
    {
        b_vec.push_back(a_vec[i]);
    }
    */

    b_vec = a_vec;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::copy` should work. you'd have to iterate over the vector manually.

Comment: This won't ever work, `std::vector` can't do that. You have to copy manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `operator=` only works on individual elements, not on whole *vectors*.

You need to define a *constructor* that converts an `A` into a `B`.

Then you can use [std::vector::assign](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/assign) rather than [std::vector::operator=](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator%3D).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct A
{
    int x, y;
    A(): x(0), y(0) {}
    A(int x, int y): x(x), y(y) {}
};

struct B
{
    int x, y;
    B(): x(0), y(0) {}
    B(int x, int y): x(x), y(y) {}

    // need to construct B from A
    B(const A& a): x(a.x), y(a.y) {}

    B& operator=(const A& a)
    {
        x = a.x;
        y = a.y;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a_test(1,2);

    std::vector<A> a_vec;
    std::vector<B> b_vec;

    for(int i = 0; i <10; i++)
    {
        a_vec.push_back(a_test);
    }

    // b_vec = a_vec; // not like this
    b_vec.assign(a_vec.begin(), a_vec.end()); // like this

    return 0;
}
```

**NOTE:** I changed some of your names because the `C++` standard says we should not begin variable names with the underscore '_'.

Answer (score 1):

Even though `a` and `b` look identical, the compiler sees them as different types, even if `a` is convertible to `b` (or vice versa). Hence, `vector<a>` and `vector<b>` are completely unrelated, so you cannot assign one to the other, and the whole assignment fails to compile.

You can use an algorithm like `std::copy`,

```
std::copy(a_vec.begin(), a_vec.end(), std::back_inserter(b_vec));
```